# cast jsondata from Ext.data.Store to list object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extjs

I have a user created button to send data from store to server side c# code.

```
    // send data through link
    function valideit() {
        var jsonData = Ext.encode(Ext.pluck(store.data.items, 'data'));
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '/Contact/Validate', params: { data: jsonData },
            success: function (result, request) {
                Ext.MessageBox.alert('Success', 'Data return from the server: ' + result.responseText);
            },
            failure: function ( result, request) { 
                Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failed', 'Successfully posted form: '+result.date); 
            } 
        });
    }
```

And C#:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Validate(object data)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            success = "This worked", failure = "Doesnt work"
        },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

this is the data i get from "data"

---

data=%5B%7B%22%C3%9AtgefandiKennitala%22%3A%224911069990%22%2C%22%C3%9AtgefandiHeiti%22%3A%22Landsbanki%20Absolute%20Return%20Stra%22%2C%22Rekstrarf%C3%A9lagKennitala%22%3A%227005942549%22%2C%22Rekstrarf%C3%A9lagNafn%22%3A%22Landsvaki%20hf.%22%2C%22ISIN%22%3A%22IS0000016913%22%2C%22Au%C3%B0kenni%22%3A%22LARS%22%2C%22Tegundheiti%22%3A%22Hlutdeildarsk%C3%ADrteinioghlutir%22%2C%22Skr%C3%A1%C3%B0heiti%22%3A%22%C3%93skr%C3%A1%C3%B0%22%2C%22Me%C3%B0all%C3%ADft%C3%ADmi%22%3A%220%22%2C%22Fj%C3%B6ldi%22%3A2101%2C%22Gengi%22%3A0.860383%2C%22Gjaldmi%C3%B0ill%22%3A%22USD%22%2C%22GengiGjaldmi%C3%B0ils%22%3A%22117.59%22%2C%22B%C3%B3kf%C3%A6rtVer%C3%B0%22%3A%22212.53%22%2C%22Athugasemd%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22%C3%9AtgefandiKennitala%22%3A%226105109810%22%2C%22%C3%9AtgefandiHeiti%22%3A%22LFESTI%20Borgart%C3%BAn%22%2C%22Rekstrarf%C3%A9lagKennitala%22%3A%22%22%2C%22Rekstrarf%C3%A9lagNafn%22%3A%22%22%2C%22ISIN%22%3A%22IS0000020105%22%2C%22Au%C3%B0kenni%22%3A%22LFEST1%2010%201%22%2C%22Tegundheiti%22%3A%22%C3%96nnurver%C3%B0br%C3%A9f%22%2C%22Skr%C3%A1%C3%B0heiti%22%3A%22Skr%C3%A1%C3%B0%22%2C%22Me%C3%B0all%C3%ADft%C3%ADmi%22%3A%2212.32%22%2C%22Fj%C3%B6ldi%22%3A984567%2C%22Gengi%22%3A1.06348%2C%22Gjaldmi%C3%B0ill%22%3A%22ISK%22%2C%22GengiGjaldmi%C3%B0ils%22%3A%221%22%2C%22B%C3%B3kf%C3%A6rtVer%C3%B0%22%3A%221047.07%22%2C%22Athugasemd%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22%C3%9AtgefandiKennitala%22%3A%224603069490%22%2C%22%C3%9AtgefandiHeiti%22%3A%22Land

---

So how can i get this data on a usable format ???

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode` to change the data into an unescaped string and then use the [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) library to deserialize the JSON string into an c# object

Answer (score 3):

Hi i wanted to answer my own question after receiving help from Jason.

on the client side, you have data in STORE.data.items (in my case ExtJS grid)

this is the action when pushing a button:

```
function valideit() {
    var jsonData = Ext.encode(Ext.pluck(store.data.items, 'data'));
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: '/Contact/Validate', params: { data: jsonData },
        success: function (result, request) {
            Ext.MessageBox.alert('Success', 'Data return from the server: ' + result.responseText);
        },
        failure: function (result, request) {
            Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failed', 'Successfully posted form: ' + result.date);
        }
    });
}
```

And on the server side:

```
[HttpPost]
            public JsonResult Validate(string data)
            {
                var response = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(data);


                List<Investments> myDeserializedObjList = (List<Investments>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, typeof(List<Investments>));


                return Json(new
                {
                    success = "This worked!"
                },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```